# AWS Athena Unnesting

Tags: json, amazon-s3, amazon-athena, unnest

I have a table in Athena using a JSON SerDe to read data from S3.  The DDL is below;

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `mbta_lines`(
  `data`  array<
            struct<
               attributes:struct<
                  color:string,
                  long_name:string,
                  short_name:string,
                  sort_oder:string,
                  text_colo:string
               >,
               id:string,
               links:struct<self:string>,
               relationships:struct<
                  routes:string
               >,
               type:string
            >
          >,
  jsonapi struct<
     version:string
  > 
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe' 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.IgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  's3://free-dp/transportation/mbta/lines'
```

The JSON is being obtained by an API, for which the JSON response looks as below;

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "attributes": {
        "color": "DA291C",
        "long_name": "Red Line",
        "short_name": "",
        "sort_order": 10010,
        "text_color": "FFFFFF"
      },
      "id": "line-Red",
      "links": {
        "self": "/lines/line-Red"
      },
      "relationships": {
        "routes": {}
      },
      "type": "line"
    },
    ....
```

The API method is returning one "row" for every "line" in the Boston metro system... "Red Line", "Green Line", etc.  All of the data is contained within one array, "Data", so the DDL only has 1 field really, and as this is an array it only has 1 row.

I know I need to use unnest to flatten this array out, but passing "attributes" to unnest is not working.  I don't know how to reference the struct under the array, as it is not named?

Answer (score 0):

select lines from mbta_lines
cross join unnest(data) as t(lines)

I hadn't tried the obvious, passing in the array itself was the trick.